# Word reading view when document opened from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word

Is there a setting in either Outlook or Word that will change the default "Reading View" for documents opened from Outlook?

Currently, it is always opening any document in Fullscreen Reading view. I would prefer the document opened in standard "Print Layout".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is actually a setting in Word:

Under Tools > Options > General, uncheck "Allow starting in Reading layout".